# Loading .txt file content and filename into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a better way to read in

- the name of a textfile and
- the content of a text file into a dataframe?

(Or is my implementation even okay?) Can I avoid storing the data in lists?

```
path =r'.../test_age7' 
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")
df_7 = pd.DataFrame()  # create empty DF
stories = []        
filenames = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    with open(file_) as f:
        textf = " ".join(line.strip() for line in f)   
    stories.append(textf)    
    filenames.append(os.path.basename(file_[0:-4]))    # extract filename without .txt

df_7["filename"] = filenames
df_7["stories"] = stories
df_7["age"] = path[-1]
```

Comment: Another approach is to convert .txt file to CSV, because Panda have [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). Here is one an [example from excel to CSV](https://github.com/sasa-buklijas/hrvatski_dinar/blob/master/xlsx_to_csv.py).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- As mention in the comments, pandas work *really* *really* well with `csv` so if you are generating the data your self you might consider to save the data in `csv` format.
- `allFiles` is just used once, dont define it; use `glob` in loop instead.
- Replace `stories` and `filenames` with just one `DataFrame`, and use `pandas.concat()`
- If you are just updating the script evertime you run it, you can just have a age variable.
- Never use `file_[0:-4]` to remove filextensions, use `os.path.splitext`.
- I guess you will run this code for a lot of diffrent ages, so make a function out of it.

---

```
from os.path import basename, splitext
import pandas as pd

def getDataByAge(age)
    res = pd.DataFrame()
    for file_ in glob.glob(".../test_age%d/*.txt" % (age)):
        with open(file_) as f:
            textf = " ".join(line.strip() for line in f)
        res = pd.concat([res,pd.DataFrame(data = {"filename" : [splitext(basename(file_))[0]], "stories" : [textf], "age" : [age]})])
    return res
```